# How to set tls in fabric-ca

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to enable tls in fabric-ca ,so :

step: I modyfied fabric-ca-clien-config.yaml

```
tls:
  # TLS section for secure socket connection
  certfiles:
       - /Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
  client:
    certfile: /Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
    keyfile: /Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
```

and

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw
```

but when I enroll:

```
export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/clients/admin
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
```

it appears

```
2018/09/28 13:36:33 [INFO] encoded CSR
Error: POST failure of request: POST https://localhost:7054/enroll
{"hosts":["jiangdeimac.cn.ibm.com"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMIIBSzCB8wIBADBdMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGA1UECBMOTm9ydGggQ2Fyb2xp\nbmExFDASBgNVBAoTC0h5cGVybGVkZ2VyMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZGYWJyaWMxDjAMBgNV\nBAMTBWFkbWluMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE6IAf/x032Df4byre\nGJ3dEI1ayE+8t8eyW5R/+ExvZJLk/OK7BrepO5HtHwYg3V2FkNwdB1iV2pq/yxTX\nthZIsqA0MDIGCSqGSIb3DQEJDjElMCMwIQYDVR0RBBowGIIWamlhbmdkZWltYWMu\nY24uaWJtLmNvbTAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNHADBEAiBzNGIF1avzD9Tbkrh3Qh2E6gVN\nKlHsXiPOZTjpSVfO0wIgCkXYx0MTQseJfjdAgXZUE7dPQqEGRg2JxTOfI2PQi5c=\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"","crl_override":"","label":"","NotBefore":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","NotAfter":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","CAName":""}: Post https://localhost:7054/enroll: x509: certificate is valid for peer0.org1.example.com, peer0, not localhost
```

the ca-server logs is"

```
2018/09/28 13:36:33 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:57762: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

so I want to know how can I set tls using fabric-ca?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure TLS on the server at start up time, you actually have the client and server configuration switched a little bit. When you start up the server, you can use the command below to specify a enable TLS and specify a TLS certificate and key. Executing this command will start the server, listening on a secure port.

```
fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw --tls.enabled --tls.certfile /Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt --tls.keyfile /Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
```

and then on the client when you enroll you need to specify the root of trust for this TLS certificate, which you can do so by using the `tls.certfiles` flag. This would look like:

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles /Users/jiangnan/Documents/GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/first-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
```

This should allow the client and server to establish a TLS connection.